# Where is my mistake in converting Cartesian to polar coordinates?

Tags: derivatives, polar-coordinates

We always believe that $dxdy$ in cartesian coordinate is equivalent to $rdrd\phi$. So let's check:

$x=r\cos\phi$

$y=r\sin\phi$.

I differentiate the equations above to derive $dx$ and $dy$

$dx=dr\cos\phi-r\sin\phi d\phi$

$dy=dr\sin\phi+r\cos\phi d\phi$

then we have

$dxdy=dr^2\cos\phi \sin\phi+rdrd\phi \cos^2\phi-rdrd\phi \sin^2\phi-r^2d\phi^2\sin\phi \cos\phi$

which is not $rdrd\phi$. However, even I neglect the terms with $dr^2$ and $d\phi^2$, I have

$dxdy=rdrd\phi \cos^2\phi-rdrd\phi \sin^2\phi=rdrd\phi(\cos2\phi)$

again I did not reach $rdrd\phi$

**Note for those who answered similar questions: Please do not refer again to the Jacobian**. I am aware of such answers and I do not oppose them. However, my question is that why we see this inconsistency between different ways of deriving the differentiation.

Comment: because things like dx are not real numbers so you cannot just manipulate them as if they are. Therefore the more reasonable question to ask yourself is why do you even expect this naive substitution to work (and saying that similar trickery works in 1D is of course not a good answer). The fact that you get the wrong answer just goes to show once again that these are not real numbers.

Comment: In this game, the rule is $dr\,d\phi=-d\phi\,dr$ (yes really). It's the calculus of *differential forms*.

Comment: @peek-a-boo is right, [they're not real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number).

Comment: @peek-a-boo. Sorry  I do not get your point and what I  wrote was based on chain rule for differentiation and it has nothing to do with manipulating symbol dx as a real number. However, even if you think this is my mistake, please clarify why in other cases - for instance if y=g(x) -we could  simply use the same technique to derive dxdy and here we can not?

Comment: @ Angina Seng. It seems so. But why?

Comment: Yes, you did treat them as real numbers when you decided to "multiply" $dx$ and $dy$ together and "expand out the brackets" and regroup the terms in the naive way. One way of answering the question (as written below) is to treat them as differential forms (which are NOT numbers) so the wedge product is anticommutative, and it is precisely this extra minus sign which changes your $-\sin^2\phi$ to a $+\sin^2\phi$, and makes everything work out, to give you $dx\wedge dy = r \, dr \wedge d\phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An expansion on @AnginaSeng's comment:

If you compare a Taylor expansion $f(x+h)\in f(x)+hf^\prime(x)+\tfrac12h^2f^{\prime\prime}(x)+o(h^2))$ with the chain rule $f(x+dx)=f(x)+dx\cdot f^\prime(x)$, we get $dx^2=0$. If this is to work for all variables, $z=x+y$ gives$$0=dz^2=dx^2+dy^2+dxdy+dydx=dxdy+dydx.$$Really, this all should be written with $dx\wedge dy$ instead of $dxdy$; it's an antisymmetric product called a *wedge product*. Similarly, $dr^2=0$, $d\phi^2=0$ and $d\phi dr=-drd\phi$. Try it now.

More generally, you can use this idea to derive the Jacobian. For example, in $2$ dimensions a conversion between two coordinate systems looks like$$dx_1dx_2=(J_{11}dy_1+J_{12}dy_2)(J_{21}dy_1+J_{22}dy_2)=(J_{11}J_{22}-J_{12}J_{21})dy_1dy_2.$$

Comment: I agree that neglecting $dr^2$ and $d\phi^2$ is risky, however, as I mentioned in the question,  if I keep those terms, again we do not reach the $rdrd\phi$.

Comment: @SMAblahi There's nothing "risky" about the anticommuting nature of differential forms. You're supposed to do$$(\cos\phi\:dr-r\sin\phi\:d\phi)\wedge(\sin\phi\:dr+r\cos\phi\:d\phi)=(r\cos^2\phi-(-r\sin^2\phi))dr\wedge d\phi=rdr\wedge d\phi.$$

Comment: @ J.G. Thanks for your clear answer. So if I understand correctly, you mean that because the $r$ and $rd\phi$ are located along perpendicular directions, the exterior products like $dr \wedge dr=0$ and the terms with $dr\wedge d\phi$ are not zero. In addition, now I can understand that why $dr \wedge d\phi =-d\phi\wedge dr$.  However, why we should look at deferential terms as some kinds of vectors?

Comment: @SMAbtahi I suppose you can think of them as vectors, albeit not in the eometric sense I think you're imagining: $df(x_1,\,\cdots x_n)=\sum_i\partial_if\cdot dx_i$ is in the span of the $dx_i$. But don't conflate $\wedge$ with the $\times$ in $3$ dimensions; the former doesn't keep us in the same space. That $\wedge$ anticommutes follows from nilpotency, as above.

Comment: @ J.G. I referred to vectors since  $dr$ and $d\phi$ have geometrical meaning. However,  the real question is why we  must use $dx\wedge dy$ instead of $dxdy$ if it is not because of geometry?