# Proving formula for a change of variables in a double integral

Tags: coordinate-systems, integration, calculus

I'm having trouble proving the formula for a change of variables under a double integral, described by the transformation of $u$ and $v$:
$$x = g(u,v)$$
$$y = h(u,v)$$

The statement to be proven:

$$\int\int_{R} dx dy$$
$$= \int\int_{S} (g_u h_v- g_v h_u) du dv $$

Subscripts denote partial derivatives. I attempted to prove it by first writing $dx$ and $dy$:

$$dx = g_udu +g_v dv$$
$$dy = h_udu + h_vdv$$

Therefore,

$$\int\int_{R} dx dy$$

$$ = \int\int_{S} (g_udu +g_v dv)(h_udu + h_vdv) $$

$$ \int\int_{S} [g_uh_udu^2 + (g_u h_v + g_v h_u)du dv + g_vh_v dv^2] $$

For reference, here is the correct integrand: $$g_u h_v- g_v h_u$$

My answer looks very different, so
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm moving this question to mathematics 

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3843920).

Comment: $g_uh_v - g_vh_u$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: @J.G. Hey, thanks very much. Your answer was very good; turns out my algebra is just very fundamentally incorrect. I don't know what a differential form is, and I doubt I will until next year, so I'm just going to leave this question alone lol

Comment: Don't worry about that term for now. What's important is you understand the argument for [anticommutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticommutative_property).